# Haskell generalization of map function for functor

Tags: list, haskell, functor, map-function

`mapFunctor :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> [f a] -> [f b]`

which this function supposed to be a generalization of map. It works the same as `map` function, and works for any Functors, not just `Maybe`.

I am stuck on it. Any hints will be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Hint: take a look at `fmap`.

Comment: Hint: think of the type signature as `(a -> b) -> ([f a] -> [f b])` - ie given a function `a -> b`, how do you get a new function `[f a] -> [f b]`? If you can't see how to do that, can you first get a function `f a -> f b`? If so, can you see how to get from that to the type you want?

Comment: when i using fmap, there is an error message that expected type: [f b], Actual type [b]

Comment: @Jacky: yes, you can not use `fmap` directly, since then it will look at the outer type constructor, see `[]` and specialize `f ~ []`. You need to combine `fmap` and `map` somehow.

Comment: Another useful thing to keep in mind is that `[x]` is syntactic sugar for `[] x`, so for example `[f a]` = `[] (f a)` and `[[a]]` = `[] ([] a)`

Comment: (the above comment refers to `[]` as type, not value)

Answer (score 1):

Play the *types* jigsaw puzzle / connect the wires (whichever metaphor you prefer):

```
mapFunctor :: Functor f 
           => (a -> b) -> [f a] -> [f b]
mapFunctor    f           []     = []
mapFunctor    f           (x:xs) = (y:ys)
  where
  --        (x:xs) :: [f a]
  --           xs  :: [f a]
  --         x     ::  f a
  --       f       ::    a  ->    b
  --  fmap f       ::  f a  ->  f b
  --  fmap f x     ::           f b 
  --        (y:ys) ::          [f b]
  --         y     ::           f b 
  --           ys  ::          [f b]
  -- mapFunctor f  :: [f a] -> [f b]
  -- mapFunctor f xs        :: [f b]
  y  =  ....
  ys =  .....
```

When you learn more you'll see that the `[]` type is also a Functor, so your function is just `fmap . fmap`. But that'll come later.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a combination of `map` and `fmap`. The [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) is a function that performs a mapping for each type that is an instance of the [**`Functor`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) and [**`map :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) is used to create a function that contains the result of applying a function to each item.

I leave it as an exercise to combine the two to a function `mapFunctor`:

```
mapFunctor :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> [f a] -> [f b]
mapFunctor = …
```